Tridion Experience Space Addon Extension. Dropdown in table toolbar
Our Tridion Experience space addon extension has a button (let's say 100% copied from the github samples: 'copySchemaItemIdsToClipboardAction'
We need to set 3 buttons there in a group "Setup A, Setup B, Setup C". In the plugin version of classic UI we have a dropdown with 3 options.
Is it possible to implement a dropdown there instead of creating 3 buttons in a row?
Thank you.

Current version of API (and application itself) doesn't have action button with dropdown options.
So the only way is to make a group with these 3 actions in a row.
